# DOM string doesn't get unescaped in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For example;

```js
var text = document.getElementById("escape").innerHTML;
alert(text);
text = "hello my name is \n cool";
alert(text);
```

```html
<p id="escape">hello my name is \n cool</p>
```

During the first alert the text inside alert is displayed as

```
hello my name is \n cool
```

but in the second it becomes

```
hello my name is 
cool
```

How can I get the first alert to be displayed as the second one?

Comment: `\n` has a special meaning in JavaScript, but not in HTML. Duong's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: Here's something to think about: if you expect `\n` in your HTML to somehow become an actual newline, then what do you think would happen if you did `"; alert("Hello!"); //`? do you think it would somehow break out and run that as code? Clearly not. Text is text, source code is source code.

Answer (score 2):

Should use textarea instead and don't use \n, just hit enter to create a new line.

```
<textarea id="escape">
hello my name is
cool
</textarea>
```

Because the p or div tag will return raw string and the \ will be escaped as \\

Comment: A newline in a `p` would also be treated as a newline. No need to use textarea.

Answer (score 1):

A string containing `'is \n cool'` in JavaScript can be represented as a list of characters:

```
["i", "s", " ", "↵", " ", "c", "o", "o", "l"]
                ^^^ newline character
```

---

Note how even though the string appears to contain backslash and `n` characters, the actual *value* of the string **does not**. This is because `\n` is an escape sequence that is evaluated as a single newline character.

---

Reading the text content of HTML that contains the literal text `is \n cool` you will end up with a string that can be represented as a list of characters:

```
["i", "s", " ", "\", "n", " ", "c", "o", "o", "l"]
                ^^^  ^^^
                 |    +- n character
                 +------ backslash character
```

---

Note how the string contains backslash and `n` characters here. `\n` is not an escape sequence in HTML, so the characters retain their values.

---

If you want HTML to contain the same value as the JavaScript string you need to include the same newline character ***properly encoded as HTML***.

This can be done via a literal newline character:

```
<div>is 
 cool</div>
```

or can be done by using an HTML encoded newline character:

```
<div>is &#10; cool</div>
```

---

Note how even though the string appears to contain `&`, `#`, `1`, `0`, and `;` characters, the actual *value* of the string **does not**. This is because `&#10;` is an HTML entity that is evaluated as a single newline character.

Comment: It's particularly worth noting that `&#10;` in your HTML source code will be treated as a single newline character when read out in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is how to interpret a string value as a JavaScript string literal. The way to interpret a string as JavaScript is (the evil) `eval`, which you can use here if you're careful enough:

```js
function interpretJSString(value) {
    return value
        .split('"')
        .map(function (v) {
            return eval('"' + v + '"');
        })
        .join('"');
}

var text = document.getElementById("escape").innerHTML;

var interpretedText = interpretJSString(text);
alert(interpretedText);
```

```html
<p id="escape">hello my "name" is \n \tcool</p>
```

The only escape sequence this will not handle is `\"`, because it takes extra precautions to prevent any `"`s in the value from breaking out of the string and causing havoc.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the first `text` with `text.replace("\\n", "\n")`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yyykk5c/4/)

Comment: Can you explain it a bit?